# How to get Access Token for uploading files on google drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api

```
   headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN}
   folder=Folder_id // google drive folder Id
   para = {"title": assignment_file_name,
            "parents": [{"id": "root"}, {'id': folder}]}
   files = {
        "data": ("metadata", json.dumps(para), "application/json; charset=UTF-8"),
        "file": assignment_file.stream.read()
    }
   response = requests.get("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/"+Folder_id,
                            headers= headers, files=files)
```

I want to upload file fetched from requests to google drive folder.
But From where to get this ACCESS_TOKEN in the headers variable?

Comment: Have you read this [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2)

Comment: no, I'll read it.

Answer (score 0):

The access token is the result of the Oauth2 request.   When you want to access private user data you must first ask for the users consent to your application accessing their data.  To do this we use Oauth2.  If you are interested in knowing how it works i have a video on it [Understanding Oauth2 with curl.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w).

Rather then coding all this manually you should consider using the Google Api python client library.  As shown in the official [Python quickstart for Drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) will walk you though how to [create credentials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwqJcyLQSSQ) (be sure to enable drive api) for your application and then how to request access of the user.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```